# Powershell Regex: Reading a multi-line string between two points

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a common enough problem with a powershell regex to read multi-line records. I've read the threads asking similar questions but can't quite get the solutions to work in my case.

My file consists of multi-line records of variable length. The records I am interested in start with a 01 or a 02 followed by a V or a M. The record ends whenever another record begins or when a batch record starting with '50' is found. The first three characters of each line identifies the record.

ie 
01V  (Start of record - content follows here)
01

I'm trying to read the individual records with a regex by identifying the start and the end.

What I have at the moment is based off this answer:
[Match everything between two words in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639252/match-everything-between-two-words-in-powershell)

```
#Read the file as a single string
$FilePath = "blaablaablaa"
$TestFile = get-content $FilePath | Out-String 

#( ?= Assert that this matches before the current position
# 0(1|2)(V|M) if the record is 01V or 01M or 02V or 02M 
# ) End assertion 
# .+? Match any number of characters, few as possible
# (?= Until a record starting with 70 is found  
# ) End of look ahead
$regex = [regex] '(?is)(?<=0(1|2)(V|M)).+?(?=70)'
echo $TestFile |  select-string -Pattern $regex
```

The above will work with single lines strings if I remove the pipe to out-sting with with the out-string pipe it returns the entire file. I'm guessing I'm not handling the /n characters correctly.

Any advice? The input file looks roughly like this:

> 00               date
>   01Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01
>   01
>   01
>   01=0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01=5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01
>   01
>   01
>   01=0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01=9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   50 xxxxxxxxxxxxx             xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$1      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$A         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$B                              0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   50 xxxxxxxxxxxx             BatchTotal
>   90 xxxxxxxxxxxx             FILETotal

The required output is splitting out the file into individual records which are delimited by a '50' or a '90' or the start of another record. This for example is the final record :-

> 01Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$1      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$A         xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$B                              0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>   01$5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: could you provide an example along with expected output?

Comment: Your description and example don't match up. There's a `01Mxxx` line that you describe as wanting to match but exclude from you desired example. You speak of lines starting with `50` to end the match, your code's comment says it'll search till it finds `70`, yet your example ends when it encounters `71`. As well the example doesn't contain `01^` as the 2nd line, it goes to `01$` immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the example to be more clear. Basically if a line starts with 01V or 01M, I want to capture everything until another line starting with 01V or 01M or 50 or 90 is encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (by your description) you also want to match the part from `01M` untill the next `01M`, and then that one separately until the `50`. This would do the trick:

```
(?gmis)^0[12][VM](?:[^\n]|\n(?!0[12][VM]|50|90))+
```

Explanation: after matching 0, 1 **or** 2, V **or** M, The part in the `(?:...)` is this:

```
[^\n]|\n(?!0[12][VM]|50|90)
```

Which means:

*match any character that **isn't** a new-line*

***OR***

*a newline that is **not followed** `(?!...)` by either the beginning of a new record **or** 50 **or** 90*.

**[online Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/eA5jB2/3)**

Comment: That works perfectly in Regex101 demo. But when I use it in my powershell script, it only returns single lines like   "01Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" instead f the full multiline record. If I pipe my file through out-string, it returns the entire file again. Must be something about the /n characters throwing the regex off.

Answer (score 0):

Using your test data:

```
@'
00 date
01Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01 01 01 01=0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01=5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01Mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01 01 01 01=0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01=9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
50 xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$A xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$B 0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
50 xxxxxxxxxxxx BatchTotal
90 xxxxxxxxxxxx FILETotal
'@ | set-content testfile.txt


$Text = Get-Content ./testfile.txt -Raw

$regex = @'
(?ms)(01(?:M|V).+?)
(?:5|9)0.+?
'@


$Records = 
[regex]::Matches($Text,$regex) |
foreach {$_.groups[1].value}

$Records[-1]

01Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$1 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$A xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$B 0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
01$5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```